# Minimalpaare Auslautverhärtung

Tags: pronunciation

Mir fallen für die Auslautverhärtung nur einige wenige Minimalpaare mit /d – t/, /z – s/ oder /ɡ – k/ ein:

- Rad – Rat
- Bund – bunt
- reis! – reiss!
- weis! – weiss
- lies! – liess
- Bug – buk

Minimalpaare mit /b – p/ oder /v – f/ sind mir noch keine eingefallen. Alles, was ich bis jetzt gefunden habe, sind Reimpaare:

- brav – Schlaf
- Bub – pup!
- Leib – Hype
- homophob – Philantrop

Gibt es mit /b – p/ oder /v – f/ richtige Minimalpaare für die Auslautverhärtung? Oder noch mehr mit den anderen Konsonanten?

Comment: Das sind dann wohl "orthographische Minimalpaare" (gleich geschrieben bis auf ein Graphem). Minimalpaare im phonologischen Sinne kann es nicht geben, wenn die Opposition stimmhaft – stimmlos aufgehoben ist. Für praktische Zwecke nimmt man doch einfach Formen mit und ohne Endung, also *erlag* – *erlagen*, *Leib* – *Leiber*, etc. und vergleicht die lautliche Form der Wurzel in den Paaren.

Comment: War das ein Kommentar oder eine Antwort?

Comment: der Hub (Tidenhub z.B.) - hup (hup mal!)
Keine Zeit, da länger herumzusuchen.

Comment: 'Alb' vs. 'Alp'?

Comment: @RalfJoerres: Mach doch eine Antwort mit deinem Beispiel – bis jetzt ist da nur eine ellenlange Erwiderung, die aber eben gerade keine Antwort erhält.

Comment: @KilianFoth: Mach doch eine Antwort mit deinem Beispiel – bis jetzt ist da nur eine ellenlange Erwiderung, die aber eben gerade keine Antwort erhält.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zwei mögliche Minimalpaare für /b – p/ im Auslaut sind mir inzwischen in den Sinn gekommen bzw. in Kommentaren erwähnt worden:

- Hub – hup!
- Raub – raup!

Für /ʋ/ und /f/ bezweifle ich, dass es Minimalpaare im Auslaut gibt, denn /ʋ/ kommt praktisch nur im Anlaut vor. Dies hat damit zu tun, dass /ʋ/ historisch gesehen auf einen Halbvokal [w] zurückgeht (wie im Englischen). Im Deutschen haben die Halbvokale mit Vokalen, auf die sie folgen, interferiert, so dass sie praktisch nur im Anlaut vorkommen. Die einzigen eingermassen einheimischen Wörter mit /ʋ/ im Inlaut, die mir einfallen, sind *ewig* und *Löwe* (vgl. aber *Ehe* und *Leu* ohne /ʋ/) – wobei ich Wörter wie *brave* nicht zähle, da sie auch mit /f/ ausgesprochen werden.

Sowieso dünkt es mich fragwürdig, die Laute /f/ und /ʋ/ als ein Fortis-Lenis-Paar wie /s – z/ oder die Plosive /p – b, t – d, k – ɡ/ aufzufassen:

- Der Fortis-Lenis-Gegensatz ist am deutlichsten im Inlaut, aber da kommt /ʋ/ wie gesagt praktisch nie vor.
- Im Süddeutschen ist /ʋ/ im Gegensatz zu den Lenes /z b d ɡ/ nicht stimmlos, so dass es besser als Approximant aufzufassen ist denn als Lenis.
- Auch die [binnendeutsche Konsonantenschwächung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binnendeutsche_Konsonantenschw%C3%A4chung) betrifft nur die eigentlichen Fortis-Lenis-Paare, nicht aber /f/ und /ʋ/.
- Ferner wäre die eigentliche Entsprechung zum Fortis-Lenis-Paar /s – z/ ein im modernen Neuhochdeutschen zusammengefallenes Fortis-Lenis-Paar /ff – f/, wobei die Fortis /ff/ in der hochdeutschen Lautverschiebung aus [p] sich gebildet hat (wie die Fortis /s/ aus [t]), während die Lenis /f/ auf [b] oder [v] zurückgeht. Beispiele für Wörter mit Fortis-ff sind *laufen, Reifen* (vgl. englisch *leap, rope),* für Lenis-f hingegen *schnaufen, Eifer.*

Comment: "... wobei ich Wörter wie brave nicht zähle, da sie auch mit /f/..." Häh? Falls das irgendwo richtig ist, hat es wenig mit Auslautverharzung zu tun. Regulär *bra(v/f), brave*, *Bravur*, *brafes Kind* vllt. aus Analogie? Im Gegenteil ist mir nicht klar, ob es in intervokalischer Stellung einen Wechsel zum Stimmhaften gibt, vgl. *aber*, Spanisch *pero* "aber", wobei Plattdeutsch *aver* gilt, s. Proto-Germanic \*aferą (*aberwitz* zu \*abuhaz, d.h. *übergeschnappt*). Für die Indogermanistik stellt p/b Wechsel vorn (pace PIE \*b, vgl. *Park*) wie hinten (pace lex Kluge) noch immer ein Problem dar.

Comment: "... vgl. aber Ehe und Leu ohne /ʋ/" ähm, eh, *Ehefrau*, *Eheweib*?! *Leu* für *Löw* ist offensichtlichst kontaminiert, vgl. *Leumund*, Altfranzösisch *loi* "Recht", klassisch immerhin *Leo*, für Löwen auf Germanischem Gebiet fehlt die Evidenz.

Comment: Für f steht ferner \*þ im Ansatz (heute noch üblich eingedeutscht *Fred* statt *thread*, historisch wohl nicht bekannt, vergleich aber *tata, atta, Vater* schon ganz richtig mit V); Fränkisch wohl auch #\*h > f (wie *tuff, tough, zäh, zerrig, durus*, wie *ziehen* zu *zerren*, *duco*).

Comment: @vectory: Das Wort _brave_ gehört zu den Wörtern mit ursprünglichem Lenis-f ebenso wie _schnaufen_ oder _Eifer_. Im Schweizer Hochdeutsch (ja, das ist auch Deutsch) werden alle diese Wörter mit Lenis-f ausgesprochen. Die Aussprache _Leu_ stellt die ältere Lautform dar, vgl. [Leu • DWB](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/leu). Aber wie dem auch sei, Wörter mit /ʋ/ im Inlaut sind im Deutschen extrem selten, und ein Minimalpaar mit /ʋ/ und /f/ im Auslaut existiert allerhöchstwahrscheinlich nicht.

Answer (score 0):

Bevor ich die von mir gefundenen Minimalpaare aufliste, möchte ich etwas zur Auslautverhärtung generell sagen:

**Auslautverhärtung bei Plosiven**

Die Auslautverhärtung ist ein Phänomen, das im nördlichen Teil des deutschen Sprachraums auftritt, und nach Süden hin immer schwächer ausgeprägt ist. Ich lebe seit mehr als 50 Jahren im Osten Österreichs (ca. 30 Jahre in Graz, 20 Jahre in Wien und seit 3 Jahren in St. Pölten), und hier kann man bei allen hier (am Ende dieser Antwort) aufgelisteten Wörtern einen gut erkennbaren Unterscheid in der Aussprache hören.

Allerdings ist der Süden des deutschen Sprachraums auch jenes Gebiet, in dem der Unterschied zwischen Lenis (»weiche« Konsonanten) und Fortis (»harte« Konsonanten) ohnehin sehr schwach ausgeprägt ist. Besonders in Wien werden alle harten Konsonanten stark abgeschwächt, was neben anderen Eigenheiten charakteristisch für den Wiener Sound ist. So wird z.B. in Wien das Wort *»Teppich«* so ausgesprochen, als würde man es wie folgt schrieben: *»Deebich«* (D statt T, B statt P und ein langes E anstelle des kurzen). Und aus dem *»Kakao«* wird ein *»Gogoo«* (langes O am Ende).

Ein Beispiel: Der Unterschied in Aussprache der Buchstaben D und T ist im Osten Österreichs bei den Paaren

> Dank - Tank
>   Deich - Teich
>   Dorf - Torf
>   Dusche - Tusche

gleich groß wie bei den Paaren

> Tod - tot
>   Rad - Rat
>   seid - seit

Nach allem was ich bisher gehört habe, soll das aber im Norden anders sein. Dort ist es angeblich so, dass bei *Dank - Tank* ein sehr großer Unterschied zu hören ist, während angeblich *Rad* und *Rat* gleich klingen. Ich kann das leider nicht nachprüfen, ich kenne zwar ein paar Norddeutsche, die leben aber schon seit Jahrzehnten in Wien und sprechen eine Mischform zwischen nördlichem und südlichem Deutsch.

Was ich für D-T gesagt habe, gilt sinngemäß auch für B-P und G-K.

Diesen sechs Buchstaben sind in der deutschen Sprache auch auf recht eindeutige Weise sechs Laute zugeordnet, die man *»Verschlusslaute«* oder *»Plosive«* nennt:

- B = [b]
- P = [p]
- G = [g]
- K = [k]
- D = [d]
- T = [t]

Dabei gibt es natürlich Ausnahmen (das *»Girokonto«* und der *»Gin«* werden nicht mit einem [g] ausgesprochen), darauf gehe ich hier aber nicht näher ein.

**Frikative**

Die Auslautverhärtung betrifft neben den Plosiven aber auch Frikative:

- [v] → [f] (brave [ˈbʁaːvə] → brav [ˈbʁaːf])
- [z] → [s] (Lose [ˈloːzə] → Los [ˈloːs])
- [ʒ] → [ʃ] (Orange [oˈraŋʒə] → orange [oˈraŋʃ])

Dazu sind zwei Dinge zu sagen:

1. In Süden des deutschen Sprachraums kommt der Laut [z] praktisch nicht vor. Dort, wo der Hamburger ein stimmhaftes [z] spricht, hört man beim Wiener ein stimmloses [s]. Das Wort Lose wird in Österreich daher nicht als [ˈloːzə], sondern als [ˈloːsə] ausgesprochen. Da im Süden des deutschen Sprachraumes der Laut [z] ohnehin generell und immer durch [s] ersetzt ist, gibt es in dieser Region auch keine explizite Auslautverhärtung, die dieses Lautpaar betrifft.

   Dasselbe gilt auch für das stimmhafte [ʒ], das im Süden immer durch ein stimmloses [ʃ] ersetzt ist.

   Aber auch der Laut [v] wird in Österreich häufig durch [f] ersetzt:

   > die brave Tochter = nicht <del>[diː bʁaːvə ˈtɔxtɐ]</del> sondern [diː bʁaːfə ˈtɔxtɐ]

   Allerdings habe ich mich mit dem Unterschied zwischen [v] und [f] noch wenig auseinandergesetzt, daher wage ich es nicht, für dieses Lautpaar Aussagen zu machen.
2. Im Unterschied zu dem Plosiven gibt es bei den Frikativen keine so eindeutige Zuordnung vom Lauten auf Buchstaben und umgekehrt. Nach orthographischen Minimalpaaren zu suchen bringt im Fall der Frikative also nichts, wenn man eigentlich nach gesprochenen Minimalpaaren sucht.

---

### Die Liste

Ich habe mir für den privaten Gebrauch eine Datenbank mit den Grundformen aller deutschen Wörter angelegt, die eine aufbereitete Form des Datenbestandes ist, der hier frei verfügbar bereitgestellt wird: http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/methoden/derewo.html

Leider enthält diese Liste keine Aussprache-Informationen, daher kann ich darin nur nach orthographischen Minimalpaaren suchen. Und damit gelingt es nur, nach den Plosiven zu suchen. Nach Frikativ-Minimalpaare kann ich leider nicht suchen.

Hier ist eine Auswahl aus den Ergebnissen:

**D - T**

- Tod - tot (Wenn dich der Tod holt, bist du tot.)
- Rad - Rat (Mein Rad ist kaputt, ich brauche deinen Rat.)
- Bund - bunt (Der Bund deiner Hose ist sehr bunt.)
- Grad - Grat (Es hat 31 Grad Celsius. Ein schmaler Grat.)
- Hund - Hunt (Der Hund bellt. Mit dem Hunt wird Erz aus der Mine transportiert.)
- seid - seit (Seid ihr alle da? Wir sind seit 10 Uhr da.)

**B - P**

Außer einigen Abkürzungen wurden keine Paare gefunden.

**G - K**

- Werg - Werk (Werg ist ein minderwertiger Faserstoff. Das Werk ist vollbracht.)
- Log - Lok (Das Log ist ein altes Hohlmaß, die Lok zieht den Zug.)
- Krieg - Kriek (Krieg und Frieden. Kriek ist ein belgisches Bier.)
- Talg - Talk (Talg ist eine Fettart. Talk ist ein Mineral.)
- Pig - Pik (Pig ist ein Würfelspiel, Pik ist eine Kartenfarbe.)
- Steg - Stek (Ein Steg ist eine kleine Brücke, ein Stek ist ein Seemannsknoten.)

Daneben gibt es viele Paar bei denen ein Wort auf *-ng* endet (bang - Bank). Nachdem *ng* aber für einen Nasal (nämlich [ŋ]) steht, also gar kein [g] zu hören ist, habe ich diese Treffer aus der Liste entfernt